# И снова о букве Ё

Tags: лингвистика

Тут уже, давным давно, правда, буква Ё обсуждалась. Вернее, обсуждался вопрос ее появления в русском языке.
Сейчас же я часто встречаю среди знатоков русского языка одобрение в сторону тех, кто на письме эту букву не опускает. Мол, "Молодец, даже букву Ё не забыл". Я же букву эту опускают всегда (кроме мало известных имен собственных) — сказывается многолетняя работа в печатных издания.
Но кто все-таки прав? Буква Ё — это действительно признак любви к языку?

Comment: > **Сейчас же** я часто встречаю... <...> **Я же** букву эту... <...>
Но кто все-таки прав? 

Такое противопоставление всё-таки бла-бла-бла называется.

Comment: Я бы сказал, это признак любви к точности выражения мыслей.

Comment: "Опускать" букву - нехорошо.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

Да, я не филолог и потому принципиально выступаю за написание буквы "ё" в любых текстах: литературных, технических, врачебных и проч. 1) ДЕТИ сразу будут приучаться к правильному произношению слов и постановке ударения в слове. 2) Взрослые не будут ломать голову, встречая новое, не знакомое для них слово: что это за слово, как с ним обращаться? 3) Какая трудность - писать букву "ё" там, где она должна быть написана? Расход печатной краски? Почему мы столько времени спорим о самом, казалось бы, пустячном деле? 4) Имеется ли подобная буква-падчерица в каком-либо другом языке на Земле? 5) В таком случае, давайте удалим и букву "й" - ещё экономнее будет печать по расходу краски. Лиха беда - начало: потом мы найдём ещё массу причин сэкономить на буквах, звуках и даже на словах, стоит только ХОРОШО подумать... Это первое, что пришло в голову в защиту несчастной буквы, третируемой филологами. Ну, сжальтесь вы над нею, господа хорошие! Дайте ей права гражданства!

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы в русском языке использовались слова:

- "все" и "всьо" (вместо "всё"),

- "мел" и "мьол" (вместо "мёл"),

- "ель" и "йолка" (вместо "ёлка").

Comment: @Галактион! Не боитесь юридического преследования за растрату бюджетных денег?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под "юридическим преследованием" и "растратой бюджетных денег"?

Comment: Если писать "о" вкупе с мягким знаком, то расход краски чуть не вдвое увеличится, а это потребует неэкономичной работы типографий и проч. Если в Академии примут Ваше предложение, Дума вынуждена будет искать того, кто сделал подкоп под Стабилизационный фонд России (и выйдут на Ваше предложение!). Все расходы на вынужденное заседание депутатов по этому вопросу присудят Вам - вовек не расплАтитесь. Пока это Счётная Палата обнаружит растрату, на Вас падут нарастающим итогом все экономические беды России, грядущий дефолт и проч. Я Вам не завидую, @Галактион. Отрекитесь от Вашего предложения!

Comment: Чему равно "чуть" в предложении "Расход краски чуть не вдвое увеличится."?

Comment: Чуть = едва ли

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения о "чуть", "юридическом преследовании" и т. п.

Comment: Забавно. Я бы сказал, "чуть" в данном предложении - ненулевая бесконечно малая величина )))

Answer (score 1):

Ну что Вы... По-моему, этот вопрос "раздули", из мухи сделали слона. Замена Ё на Е  была вызвана скорее экономикой, нежели духовностью и нравственностью,потом в некоторых ситуациях восстановлена Ё (опять-таки не с нравственных позиций , а из рациональных соображений точности), так при чём здесь любовь или нелюбовь к языку? Пусть пишут себе с Е все, кто привык, только когда это необходимо, не забывают писать правильно, чтобы не путать других людей - детей, чиновников и т.д.

Comment: Мой первый друг, мой друг бесценный!
И я судьбу благословил,
Когда мой двор уединенный,
Печальным снегом занесенный,
Твой колокольчик огласил.
При жизни Пушкина не печаталось. Написано 13 декабря 1826.

Comment: Кстати, я не против буквы Ё, у меня нейтральная позиция. Вот газета "Метро" стала печататься с буквой Ё. Конечно, раздражают слова "идёт, ещё, чёрный", но можно и к ним привыкнуть. Кстати, вспомнила: есть у меня роман Толстого 1890 года, там - "черный". 
Забавная получается ситуация: 200 лет назад безуспешно боролись с "ёкающим" произношением, а теперь борются с "ёкающим" написанием.

Comment: И по поводу перехода к правильному произношению и пониманию значений слов - боюсь, что эффект не будет очень значительным. Фактически мы обозначаем ударную позицию для слов, в которых  чередование Е/Ё наблюдается. А кстати, много ли таких слов? После шипящих их около 40-50, какое-то количество после других согласных, ну еще суффиксы-окончания добавим. 
Если уж краску экономить, то лучше ее использовать для обозначения вариантных ударений - эта проблема действительно не только не решается, но и становится всё более ощутимой.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, Ё - это вообще заимствование, так что ни о какой любви к русскому языку может идти речь? Ё пришло, кажется, из немецкого языка, где две точки над буквами - частое явление.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, в немецком всего две такие буквы с точками - ö и ü. Нет там ё. С другой стороны, использование надстрочных символов в европейских языках весьма широко. Вспомнить тот же французский - Citroën, Moët.

Comment: >в немецком всего две такие буквы с точками - ö и ü.

@gecube, три, ещё **ä**. Правда и немецкие буквы с умлаутом и точки во французских словах не чета букве Ё, так как не имеют статуса отдельной буквы. Умлаут показывает ассимиляцию гласных, а во французских словах подсказка о правильном чтении. Точки над гласными вроде приведённых вариантов из французского возможны и в английском языке, например в слове **coöperation**, и означает этот знак, что дифтонга тут нет и следует читать *кооперэйшен*, а не *куперэйшен*

Comment: >Умлаут показывает ассимиляцию гласных  
  
Ассимиляцию? O_o    
  
Я думаю, что немецкие буквы все-таки достаточно точный аналог русской Ё. Две точки у нас и в немецком выполняют роль диакритического знака, в то время как во французском это знак скорее орфографический (показывает раздельное чтение гласных).

Comment: @behemothus
> умляут (нем. Umlaut – перегласовка), фонетическое явление изменения тембра гласных а, о, и под влиянием гласного i (в герм. языках – и некоторых др. гласных) в следующем слоге (термин введён Я. Гриммом). Как фонетическое явление У. представляет собой регрессивную ассимиляцию.

БСЭ [ССЫЛКА](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/142847/Умлаут)

Answer (score 1):

Очень интересно, какая социальная группа поддерживает написание буквы Ё, - я что-то сомневаюсь, что среди этих людей много филологов. А букве Ё нужные знающие адвокаты, так как ее позицию не назовешь сильной.

Происхождение ее не из лучших. Буква Ё была введена  в конце 18 века для обозначения "нового" звука О  после мягких согласных в ударной позиции (нести - нёс). Такое произношение окончательно утвердилось в речи только к середине 19 века  - до этого просторечное "ёканье" образованными людьми не приветствовалось. Фонетические возможности языка с появлением нового звука расширились, а знаковые, скорее, только осложнились, например: был корень НЕС, а стал корень НЁС/НЕС с тем значением.

И сейчас буква Ё по-прежнему только вариант буквы Е, не стоит делать из нее самостоятельного буквенного знака. Если исключить имена собственные, то неправильно прочитать слово (если оно вам знакомо) просто невозможно. Например, мёл - мел. Вряд ли кто-нибудь в одном тексте этот мел когда-нибудь мёл. Очень редко буква Ё работает как самостоятельный знак, различая слова. Например: мы все думали - мы всё думали.

Поэтому делаем вывод: буква Ё нужна в учебных текстах и при написании НЕКОТОРЫХ имен собственных (так, всем понятное имя Пётр можно писать и с буквой Е).

ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ

Истинная и удивительная история буквы Ё (смайлик, конечно).

Создание новой буквы.

Сначала для обозначения мягкого ударного звука О применяли сочетание букв IO. Как считается, буква Ё появилась в русской письменности по предложению  директора Петербургской академии наук княгини Е. Р. Дашковой, однако известной она стала благодаря  Н.М. Карамзину, который первым стал использовать новую букву в своих произведениях с 1798 года.  Впоследствии  буква Ё использовалась в прижизненных изданиях Пушкина и других великих русских писателей того времени.

Буква Ё в  19 веке.

Звук, обозначаемый буквой Ё, в конце концов утвердился в языке, что нельзя сказать о букве Ё. С одной стороны,  «неблагородное» происхождение буквы не способствовало ее распространению. Кроме того, чередование Е/Ё МОЖНО БЫЛО просто не отражать на письме, да и для набора буквы  Ё требовались дополнительные материальные затраты. Таким образом, в текстах конца  19 века буква Ё ЧИТАЕТСЯ, НО НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ.

Буква Ё в 20 веке

Реформа орфографии  1918 года  закрепила за буквой Ё седьмое место в русском алфавите из 33 букв,  однако ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЙ ОНА ТАК И НЕ СТАЛА. Судьба  Ё могла измениться, когда в 1942 году (возможно, в связи с путаницей при чтении имен собственных) последовал указ об ее обязательном употреблении. Последующие  десять  лет  вся литература выходила с практически СПЛОШНЫМ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ  буквы Ё, но затем употреблять её стали опять только в случае крайней необходимости. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956 года ОБЯЗАЛИ использовать букву Ё только ПРИ НАЛИЧИИ ВАРИАНТОВ при её прочтении.

Comment: Лёв Толстой, давший в "Анне Карениной" одному из героев **русскую** фамилию "Лёвин" (а не еврейскую "Левин"), и Александр Алехин, которого многие называли Алёхиным, с вами бы не согласились.
Кстати, одним из первых букву "ё" стал использовать для написания своей фамилии граф Потёмкин-Таврический, до этого его фамилия писалась, насколько помню, через "iо". Ёканье было недопустимо для высокого штиля, но использовалось активно.

Comment: Осуждённый, побелённый,заселённый,восхвалённый... Скольких ошибок в произношении можно было бы избежать, если бы в текстах была буква Ё!

Comment: Кстати, об Алехине - правда. А далеко не все знают, что он именно Алехин, а не Алёхин.  
Но, с другой стороны, изначально-то в русском языке буквы Ё не было. Сравним: "сестры" и "сёстры" и т.д.

Comment: Про Алехина - вопрос очень спорный. Ссылаются на якобы его дворянское происхождение. Даже если и верно, вопрос-то стоит не так. Должно ли меняться произношение фамилии вместе с фонетикой языка? 
А то какие-то фамилии через ять писались - их что, нельзя через Е произносить, извольте исторический дифтонг выговаривать?

Comment: @behemothus, на дворянские корни фамилии ссылался согласно сам Алехин, а вот как произносить свою фамилию решает исключительно носитель. Понятно, что если в языке нет точных знаков для передачи звуков иностранного языка, что в данном случае не наблюдается, эти звуки изменяются на существующие, но и тут желание носителя прежде всего.  Так фамилия, родившегося в США журналиста  Тима Керби  (Tim Kerbi), пишется и читается через "е", так как таково желание носителя.

По поводу Алехина подробнее смотрите I раздел по[ссылке на Грамоту.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/)

Comment: 1) нес-нёс: вас не смущают осложнения вида бер-бир? может быть, упростим орфографию и будем писать "собераю" - значение слова ведь нельзя здесь ни с чем перепутать?

2) "неправильно прочитать слово (если оно вам знакомо) просто невозможно" - это лукавство: когда вы пишете (особенно в газете), вы никогда не знаете наверняка, будет ли слово знакомо читающему;

3) "только ПРИ НАЛИЧИИ ВАРИАНТОВ при её прочтении": когда вы пишете "ежик" (надеясь на "безвариантное" прочтение), вы как раз заставляете читающего перебирать варианты (вы узакониваете двузначность буквы "е").

Comment: Вы разрушаете графическую систему языка и расшатываете орфоэпические нормы, порождаете новые варианты произношения (не вызванные внутренним развитием языка).

Comment: >решает исключительно носитель
  
Это касается только ударения. Если же считать Е и Ё разными буквами, то только исполнительная власть вправе изменить написание. 

Вы путаете две вещи. Желание носителя и лингво-историческую истину (пусть даже на которую якобы ссылается сам носитель). Мне интересна только последняя. Если бы аргументация шла только по линии "он так хотел", я бы еще мог смириться при наличии весомых доказательств. Но обычно-то подают как истину о том, что так и только так по какм-то там дворянским правилам.   
  
>поссылке на Грамоту.ру   
А то я не видел...

Comment: Уважаемый stopkran, вы невнимательно читаете текст. Я занимаю НЕЙТРАЛЬНУЮ ПОЗИЦИЮ  по отношению к букве Ё и думаю, что вопрос решится в ее пользу. Я просто поясняю, почему, с моей точки зрения, академики в 1956 году отменили решение об обязательном употреблении буквы Ё. Так что ВСЕ ВОПРОСЫ ПО ВНУТРЕННЕМУ РАСШАТЫВАНИЮ ЯЗЫКА К НИМ.
А это краткие ответы на ваши вопросы: 1) чередование Е/Ё принципиально отличается от чередования Е/И; 2) Приведите пример предложения, в котором вы не смогли определить смысл слова с буквой Ё (думали, что это Е; 3) носители языка знают, что у нас нет слова ЕЖИК.

Answer (score 1):

Я не пытаюсь подменять букву "ё" буквой "е", как это делают знатоки русского языка.

Вместе с тем, будучи русским, я сознаю, что буква "ё" самая нелепая из букв русского алфавита.

P.S. По моему мнению, Андрея Рублёва следует переименовать в Андрея Рубльова.

Answer (score 0):

Очередное камлание о воде в ступе.
Вопрос полностью регулируется орфографическим правилами русского языка. 
Ё обязательно:
~ для снятия двусмысленности ("все" и "всё")
~ в именах собственных (кроме общеизвестных, но вообще-то и в них желательно)
~ в учебной литературе для детей и иностранцев.

Всё. В остальных случая пишите Е/е - и будет вам счастье.