# Ситуация с буквой 'ё'

Tags: грамматика, орфография

Хочется вновь поднять вопрос в отношении данной буквы - **ё**.

Столкнулся с тем, что не могу однозначно понять в каких случаях избегать употребления данной буквы в каких-либо печатных текстах, а в каких не избегать.

В интернете множество статей, книг, руководств, каталогов, блогов, рекламных вывесок - в некоторых из них буква **ё** используется, в других же заменена на **е**. Что правильнее?

Если мы готовим статью на сайт, следует ли в словах с буквой **ё** использовать букву **ё** или же **е**? Будет ли использование буквы **е** считаться ошибкой?

Если мы пишем книгу или руководство, как тогда поступать с буквой **ё**?

Если мы пишем блог или информационное сообщение или же рекламную информацию - нужно ли ставить **ё** или приемлемо ставить **е**?

В каких случаях буква **ё** является неотъемлемой частью текста? Как быть с именами и названиями, содержащими букву **ё**?

Особенно меня интересует вопрос читаемости текста!

- По травке шел **ежик** и **нес** он на спине кусочек яблочка. **Ежика** этого звали **Семочка** и был он **темно**-серого цвета.
- По травке шел **ёжик** и **нёс** он на спине кусочек яблочка. **Ёжика** этого звали **Сёмочка** и был он **тёмно**-серого цвета.

Какой из вариантов считается правильным и можно ли писать как в первом случае, будет ли читателю понятно?

Или если же брать официальную статью:

- Данная **прическа** с прямой **челкой** на стрижку на волосы средней длины, является, безусловно, самой **четкой** и **клевой** прической, которая подходит как молодым девушкам, так и взрослым женщинам.
- Данная **причёска** с прямой **чёлкой** на стрижку на волосы средней длины, является, безусловно, самой **чёткой** и **клёвой** прической, которая подходит как молодым девушкам, так и взрослым женщинам.

Какой из вариантов более приемлемый и наиболее подходит под нынешние правила размещения буквы **ё** в печатных текстах, если таковые правила существуют вообще?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [И снова о букве Ё](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27943/%d0%98-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%81)

Comment: Не надо в который уже раз задавать всё тот же вопрос. Он давно уже решен.

Comment: Из этих многих вопросов здесь можно было бы оставить только «ситуацию с официальной статьёй» как конкретную проблему, но со словом «клёвой» и она кажется неуместной.

Comment: Чистая вкусовщина и субъективизм, а потому пишу комментарий, а не ответ: всегда используйте букву Ё. В русском алфавите 33 буквы, ё — седьмая. Лично для меня это чёткий аргумент в пользу Ё. Кроме того, если речь о сайтах, вы повышаете удобочитаемость для пусть не очень большой, но таки части аудитории, а именно, для людей, использующих программы экранного доступа, увеличения и прочие альтернативные способы чтения, переводящие текст в речь: синтезаторам речи всегда легче правильно делать ударения, если есть Ё.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**ПАС (Полный академический справочник под ред. Лопатина). Общие правила**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=7#pp7)

Употребление буквы ё в текстах разного назначения[11]
§ 5. Употребление буквы ё может быть **последовательным и выборочным.**

**Последовательное употребление буквы** ё обязательно в следующих разновидностях печатных текстов:
а) в текстах с последовательно поставленными знаками ударения (см. § 116 );
б) в книгах, адресованных детям младшего возраста;
в) в учебных текстах для школьников младших классов и иностранцев, изучающих русский язык.

Примечание 1. Последовательное употребление ё принято для иллюстративной части настоящих правил.

Примечание 2. **По желанию автора или редактора любая книга может быть напечатана последовательно с буквой ё**.

**В обычных печатных текстах буква ё употребляется выборочно**. Рекомендуется употреблять ее в следующих случаях.
**1. Для предупреждения неправильного опознания слова**, напр.: всё, нёбо, лётом, совершённый (в отличие соответственно от слов все, небо, летом, совершенный), в том числе для указания на место ударения в слове, напр.: вёдро, узнаём (в отличие от ведро, узнаем).
2. **Для указания правильного произношения слова** — либо редкого, недостаточно хорошо известного, либо имеющего распространенное неправильное произношение, напр.: гёзы, сёрфинг, флёр, твёрже, щёлочка, в том числе для указания правильного ударения, напр.: побасёнка, приведённый, унесённый, осуждённый, новорождённый, филёр. **3. В собственных именах** — фамилиях, географических названиях, напр.: Конёнков, Неёлова, Катрин Денёв, Шрёдингер, Дежнёв, Кошелёв, Чебышёв, Вёшенская, Олёкма.

Comment: Я скажу Вам, уважаемая, Вы мне прояснили ситуацию. Получается мы в ответе за то, что пишем.

Comment: Я как редактор готовлю книги к печати с последовательным употреблением буквы ё — это книги, хоть и не для младших классов, но потенциально для чтения вслух, и это намного удобнее чтецу. При чтении про себя можно post factum сообразить, было ли там «все» или «всё», а чтецу придётся возвращаться и заново читать кусочек вслух.